# Add dynamic row after static row, then remove static row in one click event

Tags: jquery

I have a blank `tr` row in my invoice as a place holder. This allow me to pull from DB to append ajax data with `$(".item-row:last").after...` - I need for the same handler to remove the original `$(".item-row:first")` (placeholder) at the same time. I may be looking at this backwards - would it make more sense to not have the blank `tr`?

There are some cases where I would like the placeholder there as a default product like hourly rate, thus the need for it.

There are several SO the are close but don't address removing the `:first` at the same time as creating after `:last`

working: https://jsfiddle.net/xzt1krqn/

jquery:

```
$('.add-invoice').on('click', function() {
$("#invoice_div").css("display", "block");
$.ajax({
  url: '/echo/json/',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    json: JSON.stringify(myjson)
  },
  success: function(data) {

    var result = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, e) {
      var matchingItems = $.grep(result, function(item) {
        return item.customer === e.customer && item.cust_id === e.cust_id;
      });

      if (matchingItems.length === 0) {
        result.push(e);
      }
    });

    populateSelectBoxes($('#invoice_div #ddinvoice'), result);

    function populateSelectBoxes($select, result) {
      var invoices = [];
      $.each(result, function() {
        invoices.push('<li data-value="' + this.cust_id + '">' + this.customer + ' : ' + this.invoice + '</li>');
      });
      $select.append(invoices.join(''));
    }

    function populateTableRow(data, selectedProductAutonum) {
      var invoices; //fill with JSON
      $.each(data, function(i, e) {
        if (this.cust_id == selectedProductAutonum) {
          invoices = this;
          custProducts = data.filter(({
            cust_id
          }) => cust_id === selectedProductAutonum);


            $(".item-row:last").after(
              '<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_name['+i+']">Item Name</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a><a class="add-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">A</a></div></td><td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc['+i+']">Description</textarea></td><td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost['+i+']">$0</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty['+i+']">0</textarea></td><td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price['+i+']">$0</span></td></tr>');
                if ($(".delete").length > 0) $(".delete").show();
                bind();

                $('#address-title').val(invoices.customer);
                $('#address-one').val(invoices.address);
                $('#invoice_num').val(invoices.invoice);
                $('#paid').val(invoices.paid);
                $('#owed').val(invoices.sales);
                $('#auto_num').val(invoices.autonum);
                $('[name="item_name['+i+']"]').val(invoices.product);
                $('[name="item_desc['+i+']"]').val(invoices.description);
                $('[name="item_cost['+i+']"]').val(invoices.cost);
                $('[name="item_qty['+i+']"]').val(invoices.quantity);
                $('[name="item_price['+i+']"]').val(invoices.price);

        }
      });
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    }

    $('#invoice_div #ddinvoice li').click(function(e) {
      var selection = $(this).attr("data-value");
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
      populateTableRow(data, selection);
      $('ul').empty();
    });

  }
});

//$(this).closest('tr').remove();
update_total();

});
```

html:

```
    <table id="items">

      <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Unit Cost</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_name[]">Hourly Rate</textarea>
          <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
          <a class="add-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">A</a>
          </div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">$150.00</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">1</textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price[]">$150.00</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_name[]">Hourly Rate</textarea>
          <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
          <a class="add-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">A</a>
          </div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">Residential Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">$95.00</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">1</textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price[]">$95.00</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="hiderow">
        <td colspan="5">
        <!--<a id="addrow1" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a>-->
        <img src="images/rows.png" width="30px" height="auto" id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row"/>                  
        <!--<a id="storecust1" href="javascript:;" title="Store Customer">Store Cust.</a>-->
        <img src="images/customers.png" width="30px" height="auto" id="storecust" href="javascript:;" title="Store Customer"/>                
        <!--<a id="storeproduct" href="javascript:;" title="Store Product">Store Product</a>-->
        <img src="images/products.png" width="30px" height="auto" href="javascript:;" id="storeproduct" title="Store Product"/>
       <!-- added to populate invoice from DB -->
        <img src="images/products.png" width="30px" height="auto" href="javascript:;" id="fill-invoice" class="add-invoice" title="Recall Invoice"/>

        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
          <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$0.00</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
          <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$0.00</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>
          <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$0.00</textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
          <td class="total-value balance"><div id="owed" class="due">$0.00</div></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to the last row before you append after it, then remove that row, eg change:

```
$(".item-row:last").after("<tr><td></td></tr>");
```

to

```
var lastRow = $(".item-row:last");
lastRow.after("<tr><td></td></tr>");
lastRow.remove();
```

lastRow will be evaluated on the first line, so won't change to the 'now last item-row' after adding another item-row.  If you did `$(".item-row:last").remove()` it would remove the newly added row.

---

If you're adding multiple rows, then store that last-row earlier, eg:

```
var lastRow = $(".item-row:last");
$.each(data, function(i, e) {
    $(".item-row:last").after("<tr><td></td></tr>");
});
lastRow.remove();
```

this time, `$(".item-row:last")` is needed inside the loop so that the data is added in the correct order - if you used `lastRow.after` it would be added in reverse order.

There are ways to improve the efficiency of the code (eg add all the rows in a single append).

---

Perhaps an easier alternative is to mark the template/placeholder/static row so that it can be identified and removed, eg:

```
<tr class="item-row template-row">...
```

then:

```
$.each(data, function(i, e) {
    $(".item-row:last").after("<tr><td></td></tr>");
});
$(".template-row").remove();
```

Comment: there are multiple rows added at once, I've tried the `$(".item-row:last").remove()` but its not removing anything? How will storing the last row early `var lastRow = $(".item-row:last");` prevent the newly added rows from now becoming the last row?

Comment: I know my fiddle is too much code but could you give a working example...?

Comment: "*How will storing the last row early prevent the newly added rows from now becoming the last row*" - it won't prevent it, it's what you asked for.  The key being that you have a reference to the last row before something else becomes that last-row so that you can then remove the previously-last-row.

Comment: got it, and yes it worked !!! - thanks so much, racking my brain on this for hours...

Comment: Added an alternative that might make more sense and be cleaner from a process perspective.

Comment: actually I just checked - its only adding one row on calls that have 4-5 rows?

Comment: can't change the class, all the rows need to be the same for other code

Comment: It wouldn't be "changing" the class, it would be "adding" to the class.  Or you could use `<tr data-staticrow='true'...` as an example.

Comment: fixed the single row - had the var inside the .each - thanks for your help